# Not able to test play store In-App-Purchase with licensed tester account

Tags: in-app-purchase, google-play-services, android-inapp-purchase

I have uploaded an app in play store. I have created releases in Internal Test and Closed Test tracks. I have created In-App products also. Then I have added testers account for licensed testers. I have opted in using the opt-in url. But when I installed the debug build of the app in physical device with same package name which is configured in play console I am unable to test In-App products.

Actually its been 2 days since i have uploaded my app for first time. Using test accounts, I am unable to download the app from play store. It seems, google will take time to review the app and approve it. But in the docs(added url below), they have mentioned that we can test In-App products with debug builds. But I am unable to test it.

My debug build has same package name as that of app uploaded in play console. I have configured the product id correctly too. Can somebody help what might be the issue. Should I wait for google to complete the review and approve my app?

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6062777

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this post: [Testing in-app purchases on Android](https://medium.com/bleeding-edge/testing-in-app-purchases-on-android-a6de74f78878)

This should solve your issue and make this process clear for you.